# MismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

> controller

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// get
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// employee
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// no to
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// update
@RequestMapping(value = "/editemp/{id}")
public String edit(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("employee", emloyeeService.findEmpById(id));
    return "empedit";
}
```

> above code to edit employee data by id and it's working
>   this is url http://localhost:9090/springwebjdbctemplate/editemp/2

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/getallemp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String edit(@Valid Employee employee, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.getErrorCount() > 0) {
        return "empedit";
    } else {
        emloyeeService.updateEmpData(employee);
        return "redirect:/allemp";
    }
```

> exception occurs here when i try to store modified data and redirect the request to "allEmp.jsp" page 
>   this is url http://localhost:9090/springwebjdbctemplate/editemp/getallemp 
>   i think the problem in url it should be http://localhost:9090/springwebjdbctemplate/getallemp instead of above url

Comment: yes  the problem was in url in " <form  action="/getallemp" "  it working when i used Fully qualified URL <formaction="/springwebjdbctemplate/getallemp"> thanx for responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is correct. Actually the first URL http://localhost:9090/springwebjdbctemplate/editemp/getallemp is being mapped to the first method and so it is trying to convert `"getallemp"` to an `int`. And so it is getting that exception. The second URL http://localhost:9090/springwebjdbctemplate/getallemp will be mapped to the second method correctly.

Comment: yes  the problem was in url in " <form  action="/getallemp" "  it working when i used Fully qualified URL <formaction="/springwebjdbctemplate/getallemp"> thanx for responding